# I have an error when trying to add an interstitial Ad with ADMob

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I have tried to implement an interstitial Ad in my application. but i am just getting errors in my console. what am I doing wrong?

Here's my console:

```
2019-04-09 18:23:41.943930+0300 Sozo[5332:159395] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /Users/jonwilson/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/75A98A4F-6B72-431C-985C-40DA88E34B57/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2019-04-09 18:23:41.944524+0300 Sozo[5332:159395] [MC] Reading from private effective user settings.
2019-04-09 18:23:41.960135+0300 Sozo[5332:159395] <Google> To get test ads on this device, set: request.testDevices = @[ kGADSimulatorID ];
2019-04-09 18:23:43.524904+0300 Sozo[5332:159622] ATS failed system trust
2019-04-09 18:23:43.524998+0300 Sozo[5332:159622] System Trust failed for [1:0x600002d9db00]
2019-04-09 18:23:43.525164+0300 Sozo[5332:159622] TIC SSL Trust Error [1:0x600002d9db00]: 3:0
2019-04-09 18:23:43.529783+0300 Sozo[5332:159622] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)
2019-04-09 18:23:43.529941+0300 Sozo[5332:159622] Task <C47E5A3E-E77D-4D02-9AF5-A3018228B91D>.<0> HTTP load failed (error code: -1200 [3:-9802])
2019-04-09 18:23:43.530314+0300 Sozo[5332:159591] NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1200
```

I have tried watching various videos on youtube but nothing seems to suit my problem.

```
var interstitial: GADInterstitial!

@IBOutlet weak var startButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //ad ID
    interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910")

    //request ad
    let request = GADRequest()
    interstitial.load(request)

    interstitial = createAndLoadInterstitial()

    interstitial.delegate = self

@IBAction func startButtonAd(_ sender: Any) {
    if interstitial.isReady {
        interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: self)
    }
}

func createAndLoadInterstitial() -> GADInterstitial {
    let interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910")
    interstitial.delegate = self
    interstitial.load(GADRequest())
    return interstitial
}

func interstitialDidDismissScreen(_ ad: GADInterstitial) {
    interstitial = createAndLoadInterstitial()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, as mentioned in your console :

```
To get test ads on this device, set: request.testDevices = @[ kGADSimulatorID ];
```

You have to add the following code to get test ads, below your `let request = GADRequest()` :

```
request.testDevice = [kGADSimulatorID]
```

Then, you can see that you have some AppTransportSecurity issue, have you followed the ATS configuration right there : https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/app-transport-security ?

You have to disable ATS in order to receive ads without any troubles, as mentioned in Google documentation.

Comment: the documentation is dated I believe. I do not have the option for NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent on my plist. via the app transport security settings tab

Comment: 2019-04-09 20:01:09.418933+0300 Sozo[2561:545878] WF: _userSettingsForUser mobile: {
    filterBlacklist =     (
    );
    filterWhitelist =     (
    );
    noOverridingAllowed = 1;
    restrictWeb = 1;
    useContentFilter = 0;
    useContentFilterOverrides = 0;
    whitelistEnabled = 0;
}
2019-04-09 20:01:09.419044+0300 Sozo[2561:545878] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
2019-04-09 20:01:09.888619+0300 Sozo[2561:545765] Warning: Attempt to present <GADNFullScreenAdViewController: 0x101716dd0> on <Sozo.ViewController: 0x102606610> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!